# How to handle null value in TextField. [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

In this app there are two screens, the first screen displays all the user input `Strings` in a `List`, and the second screen has a `TextField` which takes the user input which will return to the first screen using `onEditingComplete`. The user will be able to navigate to the second screen by using a FAB in the first screen. When the user does not type anything in the `TextField` and returns to the previous page, the `String` which stores the user input value returns "null". I have added an `if` statement which will only return to the first page if the `TextField` is not empty but when i click on submit, it does not navigate to the first screen at all.

Could i get a suggestion on how i can modify the code so that null value from the `TextField` will not save to the `String` and navigate back to the first screen.

FAB which navigates to input(second) screen:

```
FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: ()async {
//                setstring(String result){
//                  widget.updatestring = result;
//                  return widget.updatestring;
//                }
                String result1 =   await Navigator.push( // string which stores the user entered value
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => InputScreen(), //screen which has TextField
                  ));
              setState(() {
//                widget.updatestring = result1;
                TodoList(result1);
//              setstring(result1);
                addItem(result1, false); // function which adds the entered task in a list
              });
            },
            heroTag: "btn2",
            child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Color(whitecolor),), backgroundColor: Color(redcolor),),
```

Textfield which takes user input :

```
                     TextField(
                        autofocus: true,
                          onEditingComplete: (){
                            String textToSendBack = taskcontroller.text;
                            if(taskcontroller.text.isNotEmpty) {
                              Navigator.pop(context, textToSendBack);
                            }
                            },
//                        onSubmitted: (value) {
//                          String textToSendBack = taskcontroller.text;
//                          Navigator.pop(context, value);
//                          },
                        maxLength: 100,
                        controller: taskcontroller,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "enter tasks here"
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(height: 1.2, fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black87),
                      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
String textToSendBack = taskcontroller.text;
       if(textToSendBack != null){
              Navigator.pop(context, textToSendBack);
          }
```

that will only take you back to the other screen when the Text isn't empty. otherwise, you stay on the current screen waiting for valid input.

I hope I understood you question correctly.

Comment: it navigates back to the first screen but the ```String``` is still saved with blank space. I want it to navigate to the first screen without saving anything in the ```String textToSendBack```.

Comment: ok i solved it by adding the same condition (```String.isNotEmpty```) to the function which adds the tasks and now it does not save to the string. Thank you for helping out :).

Answer (score 3):

For me it's working fine  **isEmpty** or **isNotEmpty**

```
_titleController.text.isEmpty
_titleController.text.isNotEmpty
```